# Could not build wheels for loris, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I'm trying to istall loris library, but always get the same error.

```
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with 
exit code 1104
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for loris
  Running setup.py clean for loris
Failed to build loris
ERROR: Could not build wheels for loris, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm using python 3.8.10. I have done pip install pyproject.toml and it is installed then also it's showing the same error. I've already done installation Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, but that hasn't solved the problem too.